# Achieving smooth css keyframes and animations in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, css-animations

I have created a slide up CSS animation which run pretty smooth on webkit browser. However is quite jerky on Firefox on Windows although i have used the `-moz-` prefix in my css.

Just wondering if anyone has experience this issue and what they did to overcome the issue.

I have upload code onto jsfiddle: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/zMxUw/4/)

Comment: You forgot to include `jQuery` lib to your fiddle. See the **[working one](http://jsfiddle.net/zMxUw/1/)**

Comment: Cheers, First time i'm using fiddle, i was wondering why it wasn't working in fiddle

Comment: I don't think using `-moz` will somehow help you for it is fully replaced by the standard writing (i.e. `animation-duration`) on the newer FF.